# Visual Studio Keyboard Shortcut / Hot key to Publish Current File

Tags: visual-studio, keyboard-shortcuts, hotkeys

I'm aware of Build.PublishSelection as a shortcut to pull up the publish project window (and publish the entire project), but I would like to bind something to publish just the current file I'm editing. You can right click the file in solution explorer and publish it, but I have to do this 200+ times a day and those seconds add up.

Any hotkey command to do this or other possible workaround?

Comment: You should use msbuild

Answer (score 7):

In Visual Studio Enterprise 2017 this is the shortcut sequence (basically a path to the publish menu item):

1. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> - opens the "**B**uild" menu
2. <kbd>H</kbd> - selects: "Publis**h** *your_solution_name*", selects the "Publish" button
3. <kbd>Enter</kbd> - confirms

Comment: just fyi, my favorite way to publish is, right click on the toolbar and enable Web One Click Publish toolbar. Then you get one button to click to do it. Also, this used to be able to be bound to a key in vs2010 and earlier.

Comment: @rocketsarefast, but how to assign a shortcut for that action?

Comment: @Aviw, i cant assign a keyboard shortcut to the toolbar button unfortunately, but at least its just one mouse click. Not great but better than nothing.

Answer (score 5):

**Visual Studio 2022**: <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd>, <kbd>H</kbd> and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

**Visual Studio 2019**: <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd>, <kbd>H</kbd> and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

**Visual Studio 2017**: <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>'</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

**Creating a shortcut (works in any version):** Go to `Tools > Options > Environment > Keyboard`, look for `Build.PublishSelection`, in `Press shortcut keys` type e.g. <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> and click on `Assign`.

Answer (score 3):

For Visual Studio 2015:

`Alt + ¨, Alt + P` will publish the currently *selected* file(s).

The `¨` key is the one just left of the `enter` key.